# How do I access my attic through a locked panel door? What kind of key do I need?

Tags: attic, lock, attic-door

I have a leak in my roof that's coming through my ceiling. I wanted to get up into my attic to track it down and get a bucket underneath it as much as I can, but I'm not sure what type of key I need to open my attic door.

It looks to have two keyholes but I don't have any sort of attic key.

[image: full door]
[image: closeup of keyhole]
[image: light inside keyhole]
[image: light inside keyhole]
[image: light inside keyhole]

I went to Home Depot and Lowe's to search for "attic key" but nothing is really jumping out at me in regards to what tool I need.

I've tried pushing up to see if you just push up to release some mechanism and then the door opens up downwards, but that doesn't look to be the case.

What do I need to open this hatch?  I want to get up there ASAP.

Comment: Abnormal for access to be locked unless it's a rental - is it? If so, call the landlord about the leak.

Comment: Might be more of a catch instead of a lock.  Threaded holes so might need something like a bolt to pull/turn to release the catches.

Comment: Have you tried a quarter twist with a screwdriver?

Comment: It appears to need a coffin key. I would try various sized allen wrenches until finding something that turns it.

Comment: If you don't own this building and the roof is leaking behind a locked door you very much should get the landlord to deal with it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need a generic key that looks like this on the right:
[image: industrial cabinet key]

[source Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805246505425.html?src=google&aff_fcid=1d3c31d36c3b485c98efcd9915e70ac5-1705607664224-01108-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=1d3c31d36c3b485c98efcd9915e70ac5-1705607664224-01108-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=1f741b1f304c42cfbb6b264d086f6850&afSmartRedirect=y&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt)

Another picture:

[image: Amazon key]

[source Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HQ2X3PC)

Also seen on McMaster-Carr:

https://www.mcmaster.com/products/cabinet-keys/

You'll need the "female 2-way" style.

Comment: That's what came to mind for me, too. They're common with bathroom dispensers of various sorts.

Comment: Yes, that looks to be exactly what I need, that looks like it will slot right in.  This seems to be the only thing on Home Depot I can find that has that female 2-way style (top left in the product picture):

Universal Control Cabinet Key
https://www.homedepot.com/p/KNIPEX-3-1-2-in-Universal-Control-Cabinet-Key-00-11-02/205944403

I don't know if the size is right, but that looks to be the only thing I can find searching Home Depot and Lowes.

I've called several local locksmiths and none of them had any idea when seeing the photos.

Comment: That Home Depot key could work, if it's long enough.